# jquery ReferenceError: widget is not defined in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i create class in js file

```
Widget = Class.create();

Widget.prototype =

{

};

var widget = new Widget();
```

i also call this js file in header

i call this object in php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

widget.options.URL = 'http://example.com';

</script>
```

error: ReferenceError: widget is not defined

how to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function `Class.create()` as of native javascript.

If you are using jQuery you should wrap your code inside of

```
$(function() {
    ...
}
```

So for your JS file it will be:

```
$(function() {
    Widget = Class.create();

    Widget.prototype =
    {
    };

    var widget = new Widget(); 
}
```

And for your php file

```
$(function() { widget.options.URL = 'http://example.com'; }  );
```

P.S. With this code I assume that you're using jQuery and some plugin for Class.create, otherwise I suggest you to use native JS:

```
function Widget() {} 
Widget.prototype = {} 
var widget = new Widget();
```

Comment: my code not work in only wordpress. core php it's working. this not work in wordpress.

Comment: @ManishJesani there is no connection between wordpress and code you writing.

Comment: i know but this not work in wordpress. same error coming

Comment: @ManishJesani Once again, you sure that you've got a plugin for Class.create? There as no such function as of native js neither jquery